# Search tabs do not come up during an advanced search

Tags: civireport

Could you help me with this problem please : Search tabs do not come up during an advanced search.

Comment: Someone might be able to help you if you add missing details to your question, such as "what are you trying to do?" "what version of CiviCRM are you using?" "did it work before?" "when did it stop working?" "what are the steps to reproduce the problem?"

Comment: Inspect your CSS in the browser. It might be an upgrade has changed the CSS so your black text in on a black background in the tab legend - or white on white etc.